# Spring Controller - forking request, return value before long run function ends

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, callback, fork

I have controller and long run function in it, like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/deposit")
public class DepositController {

    @RequestMapping
    public ModelAndView getNewJob(long userId, Model model) {
        //execute function that can runs a lot of time ...
        longRunFunction();

        return new ModelAndView("jobTasks");
    }

    public void longRunFunction(){
        // process long run function
    }
}
```

My question is : 
How can I execute the longRunFunction() 
and return ModelAndView("jobTasks") answer to the browser  without waiting for the end of the function?
Thank you !

Hi, I found nice example here http://krams915.blogspot.co.il/2011/01/spring-3-task-scheduling-via.html

Comment: It is possible to do it with some kind of sync spring function configurations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using Asynch support in Spring Framework, essentially delegate the long running task to another service, the method of which is annotated with `@Async` annotation, this task would then be executed by a threadpool and control will return back to your caller immediately.

Here is much more detailed reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async

```
public class SampleBeanImpl implements SampleBean {

  @Async
  void longRunFunction() { … }
}
```

Comment: I am newbie in spring, How I create SampleBeanImpl in DepositController and what is the content of SampleBean interface ?

Comment: @prilia, you can create a new interface called `SampleBean` - call it something more meaningful, implement this interface using a class, the method in the new class should have the @Async interface. I would recommend going through the reference document that I have provided for more details though

Answer (score 0):

Add `@Async` to the method declaration of `longRunningMethod`. But to make this work without AspectJ weaving you need to put this method in an other bean.